# OnParticleTrigger(): How to get the collider a particle entered?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system

I am trying to extinguish a fire in Unity3d. I have 2 particle systems: fire and water. Since 2 particle systems can't collide, i added a box collider to the base of the fire (where isTrigger is checked). I use `OnParticleTrigger()` to damage the health of the fire. But now I want to have multiple fires so I need to know which fire/box collider a particle entered. I know you can't get the collider like `OnTriggerEnter()`, but is there a way to work around it?

I tried `OnParticleCollision()`, but the water particles bounce of the box collider (this is not the visual effect I want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each trigger event I get all the particles that entered a collider. Then, for each of those particles, I check which box collider they entered with `collider.bounds.Contains()` and damage the fire the box collider belongs to. I don't know if this is the best way to do it (probably not), but it works for now.

```
private void OnParticleTrigger()  
    {

        //Get all particles that entered a box collider
        List<ParticleSystem.Particle> enteredParticles = new List<ParticleSystem.Particle>();
        int enterCount = waterPS.GetTriggerParticles(ParticleSystemTriggerEventType.Enter, enteredParticles);

        //Get all fires
        GameObject[] fires = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Fire");

        foreach (ParticleSystem.Particle particle in enteredParticles)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < fires.Length; i++)
            {
                Collider collider = fires[i].GetComponent<Collider>();
                if (collider.bounds.Contains(particle.position))
                {
                    fires[i].GetComponent<Fire>().Damage();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```